# Symfony: stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle incompatible with Symfony upgrade from v2.8 to v3.0

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to update Symfony from version `2.8` to version `3.0`.

I updated the version of `symfony/symfony` in `composer.json` and ran  `composer install`.

I don't have the bundle `symfony/framework-bundle` in `composer.json`.

I'm using PHP `7.1.3`.

I have the following error:

```
Problem 1
- stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle v1.3.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.7|~3.2|~4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.49], symfony/framework-bundle[v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.28, v2.7.29, v2.7.3, v2.7.30, v2.7.31, v2.7.32, v2.7.33, v2.7.34, v2.7.35, v2.7.36, v2.7.37, v2.7.38, v2.7.39, v2.7.4, v2.7.40, v2.7.41, v2.7.42, v2.7.43, v2.7.44, v2.7.45, v2.7.46, v2.7.47, v2.7.48, v2.7.49, v2.7.5, v2.7.50, v2.7.51, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.29, v2.8.3, v2.8.30, v2.8.31, v2.8.32, v2.8.33, v2.8.34, v2.8.35, v2.8.36, v2.8.37, v2.8.38, v2.8.39, v2.8.4, v2.8.40, v2.8.41, v2.8.42, v2.8.43, v2.8.44, v2.8.45, v2.8.46, v2.8.47, v2.8.48, v2.8.49, v2.8.5, v2.8.50, v2.8.52, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9, v3.2.0, v3.2.1, v3.2.10, v3.2.11, v3.2.12, v3.2.13, v3.2.14, v3.2.2, v3.2.3, v3.2.4, v3.2.5, v3.2.6, v3.2.7, v3.2.8, v3.2.9, v3.3.0, v3.3.1, v3.3.10, v3.3.11, v3.3.12, v3.3.13, v3.3.14, v3.3.15, v3.3.16, v3.3.17, v3.3.18, v3.3.2, v3.3.3, v3.3.4, v3.3.5, v3.3.6, v3.3.7, v3.3.8, v3.3.9, v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13, v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20, v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.23, v3.4.24, v3.4.25, v3.4.26, v3.4.27, v3.4.28, v3.4.29, v3.4.3, v3.4.30, v3.4.31, v3.4.32, v3.4.33, v3.4.34, v3.4.35, v3.4.36, v3.4.37, v3.4.38, v3.4.39, v3.4.4, v3.4.40, v3.4.41, v3.4.42, v3.4.43, v3.4.44, v3.4.45, v3.4.46, v3.4.47, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8, v3.4.9, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13, v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7, v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.2, v4.1.3, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9, v4.3.0, v4.3.1, v4.3.10, v4.3.11, v4.3.2, v4.3.3, v4.3.4, v4.3.5, v4.3.6, v4.3.7, v4.3.8, v4.3.9, v4.4.0, v4.4.1, v4.4.10, v4.4.11, v4.4.12, v4.4.13, v4.4.14, v4.4.15, v4.4.16, v4.4.17, v4.4.18, v4.4.19, v4.4.2, v4.4.20, v4.4.21, v4.4.22, v4.4.24, v4.4.25, v4.4.26, v4.4.27, v4.4.3, v4.4.30, v4.4.31, v4.4.34, v4.4.36, v4.4.37, v4.4.38, v4.4.39, v4.4.4, v4.4.40, v4.4.41, v4.4.42, v4.4.43, v4.4.44, v4.4.45, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7, v4.4.8, v4.4.9].
```

This is my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.0",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.2.1",
    "khepin/yaml-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "gregwar/image-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
    "misd/phone-number-bundle": "^1.1",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
    "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "^1.0",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.0",
    "gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle": "^0.2.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.2",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "evence/soft-deleteable-extension-bundle": "^1.3",
    "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "^2.0",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
    "twig/twig": "2.6.*"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
    }
],
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
```

Comment: "symfony/framework-bundle" isn't in your composer.json, but "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle" is, and as the part of the message you quoted clearly states "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle v1.3.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle". Since you haven't shared the full error message, it's hard to help further - presumably it goes on to explain what _other_ requirement conflicts with that one.

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade to Symfony 3.0? That's out of support since years, the last security fixes were made in 2017. You should at least use Symfony 3.4, which was supported until 2021

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` in version `v1.3.0` is not compatible with Symfony `v3.0.x`.

It is only compatible with Symfony versions: `~2.7|~3.2|~4.0`.

Update to a Symfony `v3.x` version greater than `v3.2.0` or try to find a version of `stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle` that is compatible with Symfony `v3.0.x` to resolve the issue.

Note: Symfony `v3.0` is not maintained any more - see: [Maintained Symfony Branches](https://symfony.com/releases#maintained-symfony-branches).

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, I choose a version of the stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle compatible with version 3 of symfony.
However, I have other errors of the same style on several bundles.
I'm switching to version 3 because I want to migrate from version 2.8 of symfony to version 5.4.
I am trying to perform this migration step by step.
from 2.8 -> 3.0 -> 3.4 -> 4.0 etc..

Do you think this is the right method to perform a migration of this type?

Comment: That's the recommended approach. Give [rectorphp/rector-symfony](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector-symfony) a try. It will ease the upgrade process a lot.

Comment: @oracle972 At the very least you should take a moment and create a fresh 5.4 project using Symfony CLI and then try to install all your third party stuff because quite a few packages have fallen by the way side.  Plus you get an idea of what your final destination look like.  In fact, if your project is non-trivial then you might want to jump to 6.x.  The LTS 6.4 is only a year or so away.